# Getting 401 unauthorized after using JWT bearer token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, authorization, bearer-token

I wanna create authentication and authorization for my web api in .net 8.0.0(which is important considering in 7.0.0 in another project i was able to use the bearer with the same methods as described below), and i wanted to use JWT Bearer token for this. I have a GetRequest which has an authorize attribute, so only authorized users can make a request, but it doesn't work. After login, i successfully get the token, but when i paste it(using swagger ui authorize button) and wanna use the GetRequest, i get the 401 error, any ideas why?

I have two files which i think connected, one is called tokenservice, and the other is the program.cs:

```
public class TokenService : ITokenService
{
    private const int ExpirationMinutes = 30;

    public string CreateToken(IdentityUser user)
    {
        var expiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(ExpirationMinutes);
        var token = CreateJwtToken(
            CreateClaims(user),
            CreateSigningCredentials(),
            expiration
        );
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }

    private JwtSecurityToken CreateJwtToken(List<Claim> claims, SigningCredentials credentials, DateTime expiration) =>
        new JwtSecurityToken(
            "apiWithAuthBackend",
            "apiWithAuthBackend",
            claims,
            expires: expiration,
            signingCredentials: credentials
        );

    private List<Claim> CreateClaims(IdentityUser user)
    {
        try
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, "TokenForTheApiWithAuth"),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id ?? ""),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName ?? ""),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email ?? "")
            };
            return claims;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }

    private SigningCredentials CreateSigningCredentials()
    {
        string secretKey = "!SomethingSecret!";
        byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);

        // Trim or pad the key to make it exactly 32 bytes
        Array.Resize(ref keyBytes, 32);

        return new SigningCredentials(
            new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyBytes),
            SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256
        );
    }
}
```

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPageService, PageService>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<UsersContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITokenService, TokenService>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ProductDataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ProductDataContext"));
});

// Add Identity
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<UsersContext>();

// Configure Swagger
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(option =>
{
    option.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Demo API", Version = "v1" });
    option.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please enter a valid token",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });
    option.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id="Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[]{}
        }
    });
});

// Configure Authentication
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = "apiWithAuthBackend",
            ValidAudience = "apiWithAuthBackend",
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                PadKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("!SomethingSecret!"), 32)
            ),
        };
    });

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Comment: Can you show the endpoint that is returning the 401 ?

Comment: And also how to you send the token to your api via your client/swaggerUI

Answer (score 0):

.Net8 has built-in solution to integrate asp.net identity and "jwt bearer" authentication for API. You could try following:
Create a new webapi project, then add 
AppDbContext.cs

```
    public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=192.168.2.68;Initial Catalog=UserAuth4;User ID=sa;Password=xxxxx;TrustServerCertificate=True");
        }
    }
```

program.cs    (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore)

```
buidler.Services.AddSwaggerGen(.....);
...
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>();
builder.Services
    .AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
...
app.MapIdentityApi<IdentityUser>();
```

Then add [Authorize] attribute to weatherforecast controller.
Upgrade database and test:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, turns out the problem was the way I tried to implement the logic was only  working in .net 7.0 but not in 8.0